# Count number of cells containing specific text for same dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

my worksheet has 5 columns:

1. A - Dates (Starts from 12-03-2018 and will go on continuing)
2. B - Customers (Name of customers)
3. C - Preference (Lunch or Dinner)
4. D - Count of Lunch for 12-03-2018, 13-03-2018 and so on
5. E - Count of Dinner for 12-03-2018, 13-03-2018 and so on

So for date 12-03-2018, there are multiple customers (column B) with either Lunch or Dinner preference (column C). How do I calculate count of total number of Lunches (column D) for dates 12-03-2018, 13-03-2018 and so on?

Comment: I have tried this: =COUNTIF(D:D,"Lunch"). But it gives me count for all the dates. I want count for same dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have more than one condition (date and lunch/dinner), you need to use [`COUNTIFS()`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function) instead of `COUNTIF()`.

This formula, filled down and right from D2, gives the results shown below.

`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,$D2,$C$2:$C$21,E$1)`

[image]

Note the added column D listing the dates to be counted.  This simplifies the filling of the formula into the small table shown.  You could also eliminate the extra Date column, and use an `IF()` statement to put the counts adjacent to the first occurrence of the Date in column A.

`=IF(A2<>A1,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,$A2,$C$2:$C$21,D$1),"")`

Comment: Thank you so very much. Works perfectly well! I upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the column D contains for each row the number of lunches for the date specified in column A of the row.

You can then use this formula:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, DATE(2018, 03, 12), D:D)
```

From MS docs:

> `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`
>
> The **SUMIF** function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> - **range** : The range of cells that you want evaluated by criteria.
> - **criteria** : The criteria [...] that defines which cells will be added.
> - **sum_range** : The actual cells to add, if you want to add cells other than those specified in the **range** argument.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I tried your formula. Unfortunately, it didn't work. The formula does not include 'Lunch', so how is it counting the cells containing 'Lunch'?

Comment: The original post said "count of total number of Lunches for 12-03-2018". I interpreted that as "sum of column D (count of Lunches) where column A == 12-03/2018". You did not mention that the column C was to be taken into account.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the bad question. I have edited it. Please check again. I wanted the count of total number of lunches for each day.